# How to fully dump / print a variable to console in Flutter?

Tags: debugging, flutter, flutter-test

This is a follow-up to [this Dart question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42440061/how-to-fully-dump-print-variable-to-console-in-the-dart-language).

Since Flutter doesn't support reflection and we can't use mirrors, how would you go about debugging, let's say an instance of `firebase_database DatabaseReference` ?
I'm trying to write tests, and knowing what key/values my reference contains will make it easier for me to write a proper test.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

since Dart 3.12 you can use `inspect(object)` to achieve this

You need to import the developer package:
`import 'dart:developer';`

Comment: Got any more info on Dart 3.12? I can't find anything about it online. "flutter doctor" says I have 2.8.4 and I find no indication of that being outdated. Or any more info on how to use this in general might be helpful, actually.

Comment: https://dartcode.org/releases/v3-12/#debugger-inspect vscode

Comment: BRO! This is awesome! Thanks.

Comment: What console does it print to? i don't see any `Debug Console` in the latest Android Studio (Bumblebee 2021.1.1.1).

Comment: In case someone didn't know how to import it like what happened to me ..`import 'dart:developer';`

Comment: Doesnt do anything.

Answer (score 2):

If you expect to have a built-in easy solution, then sorry : You can't.

**BUT** you can use plugins to serialize your own code, such as [built_value](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart). And print the serialized object.

On the other hand, if you want to print *external* code (DatabaseReference for instance), you'll have to manually transform that object in a combination of Map, List, and int/String/double.

Comment: built_value's defaultb`toString()` usually works well already, no need to serialize.